# Android AnimationDrawable start

Tags: android

I'm using AnimationDrawable to show missing network connection.
Show/hide logic is linked to network status change receiver. It works fine.
But when start activity knowing status and try to start animation - animated drawable shows and freezes on first frame. I've read in documentation - 'do not start animation in OnCreate'.
So I wrote code in onResume, but animation still not playing - only shows first frame.
Starting from button or event works fine.
Tried to start with separate thread and wait some time - but this doent sounds good.

Any idea?

This code works when called from net status change handler

```
private void _NetStatus(boolean start)
{
    if (start)
    {
        m_NetStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        m_NetStatusFrameAnimation.start();
    }
    else
    {
        m_NetStatusFrameAnimation.stop();
        m_NetStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. After trying some samples advising me to use new Runnable at end of onCreate - I tried to start animation when activity shows on screen:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
```

Works fine for now.